# Joining same table on itself

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000, user-agent

One of my table stores the UserAgent from the user's browser along with the corresponding UID associated with it, with some other data. This occurs every time a user logs in. So they will have many entries per user. I am trying to query this table to find some unique users based on qualities.

For example, I am trying to find only users that have used IE6 and no other browsers. The closest I can get so far is through this method:

```
select distinct (U.UID) from TABLE1 tb1
inner join TABLE1 tb2 on tb1.UID = tb2.UID
where tb1.UserAgent like '%MSIE 6.%'
and tb2.UserAgent like '%MSIE 6.%'
```

This seems to return users whom have used IE6 and any other browser as well. I am trying to find basically the opposite of this. Users that have used IE6 and IE6 only. I also tried the one below but didn't quite work either because a good chunk of this users had other entries with non IE6 browsers.

```
select distinct (U.UID) from TABLE1 tb1
inner join TABLE1 tb2 on tb1.UID = tb2.UID
where tb1.UserAgent like '%MSIE 6.%'
and tb2.UserAgent not like '%MSIE 6.%'
```

I think I am on the right track but could be way off here.

TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select user with user agent `like '%MSIE 6.%'` who do not have any other user agent. The inner query returns users who have not used `'%MSIE 6.%'`

```
select distinct tb1.UID from TABLE1 tb1
where tb1.UserAgent like '%MSIE 6.%' and
      NOT EXISTS ( select tb2.UID from TABLE1 tb2
                   where tb1.UID = tb2.UID AND 
                         tb2.UserAgent not like '%MSIE 6.%' )
```

You can even use `NOT IN` instead of `NOT EXISTS` like `tb1.UID NOT IN (...)`.

```
select distinct tb1.UID from TABLE1 tb1
where tb1.UserAgent like '%MSIE 6.%' and
      tb1.UID NOT IN ( select tb2.UID from TABLE1 tb2
                       where tb2.UserAgent not like '%MSIE 6.%' )
```

The where clause condition `tb1.UserAgent like '%MSIE 6.%' and` can also be dropped without any side effects as the `NOT` and the inner query makes sure that the user's agent matches %MSIE 6.%

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct (tb1.UID) from TABLE1  tb1
where not exists (
                   select 1 
                   from TABLE1 
                   where UID = tb1.UID and UserAgent not like '%MSIE 6.%'
                 )
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to join and much faster than JOIN/NOT EXISTS:

```
select UID 
from TABLE1
group by UID
having max(case when UserAgent like '%MSIE 6.%' then 0 else 1 end) = 0
```